# Excluding comments that belong to top post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models: posts, questions, and comments where posts have many questions and questions have many comments (Posts also have many comments through questions). I have a method that looks like this:

```
def home
  @post = Post.where(:top => true).limit(1)
  @comments = Comment.order("created_at desc")
end
```

The thing is, I don't want any of the comments from @comments to belong to the post from @post. How do I exclude comments that belong (through a question) to the first post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exclude comments belonging to `@post` with `where.not`:

```
@comments = Comment.order("created_at desc").where.not(post_id: @post.id)
```

More info on `where.not` in [this blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot).

As the OP added in the comments below, if there is another model between `Post` and `Comment` (in this case: `Question`), then you can do the following:

```
@comments = Comment.order("created_at desc").where.not(question_id: @post.question_ids)
```

Comment: Ah perfect, I wasn't aware of where.not. One thing though which I should have included in the question -- I have a model in between posts and comments called questions so comments only have a question_id. I'm not sure of the correct syntax to say question_id.post: @post.id

Comment: @user2759575 Ok, check out my edited answer, which (hopefully) reflects the addition of questions. However, I have no way of knowing what the relationship between questions and posts (many-to-many, one-to-many, etc.) is based on the context you've given me. Same with questions and comments. Can you add all of this information (including your comment above) to the question? It would have been good to put all that info in the question from the start.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I edited the question with more details. This is getting closer but since  a post has_many questions @post.question doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me an 'undefined method `question_ids' for nil:NilClass' error.

Comment: Do you still have the line `@post = Post.where(:top => true).limit(1)` above it? The `undefined method ... for nil:NilClass` error is saying that `@post` is null, which either means that it isn't being set, or there is no post where `top` is true.

Comment: Oops, it's named something else and I forgot to change it back. Now it's giving me 'undefined method `comment_ids' for #<ActiveRecord...'

Comment: I wrote `question_ids`, not `comment_ids`... Hopefully that will fix it.